# Thread in Window

Tags: wpf

Here is my code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Thread ProgressThread;
    Window w;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            w = new Window();
            RoundProgressBar objprogress=new RoundProgressBar();
            w = new Window();
            w.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 50, 0);
            w.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            w.Height = 80;
            w.Width = 80;
            w.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            w.AllowsTransparency = true;
            w.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            RoundProgressBar Progress = new RoundProgressBar();
            w.Content = objprogress;
            w.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            w.ShowDialog();
            w.Content = Progress;
            w.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            w.ShowDialog();

            w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
            w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        ProgressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        ProgressThread.Start();
    }
}
```

when i click the button thread start the progress bar in middle of the screen .when i change main screen  that progree bar  window not changing .

I want to display that progress bar middle of that window . if i move anywhere.

w.Owner = this;

i know with the help of this code this will work perfect.but i am working in thread so this error is occured

"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Please help me out from this problem

Answer (score 2):

The UI objects are on the UI thread. You want to have a background thread that monitors the progress, but then anything you want to update on the UI, you need to dispatch back to the UI thread again.

Something along these lines:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(UpdateUI);
}

private void UpdateUI() {
   Dispatcher.Invoke(
      new Action(() => { 
          textBox1.Text = "Henk"; 
          // etc etc, this would be your normal code
      })
  );
}
```

This article explains it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx.

If can use [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx), then you should look at [this](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2010/11/c-50-and-sample-that-made-me-go-wow.html) example. That's how this pain mostly goes away for these issues.

Regards, Gert-Jan